# @Parcelize not resolved with androidExtensions experimental mode set to true

Tags: android, kotlin-android-extensions, gradle-kotlin-dsl

After switching to Gradle Kotlin DSL Gradle is not able to resolve `@Parcelize` annotation or package `import kotlinx.android.parcel.Parcelize` ("Unresolved reference" error). That happens with stable Kotlin plugin and latest Canary one. Build fails in Android Studio and also from console when using Gradle Wrapper.

Top level build.gradle.kts

```
buildscript {
    repositories {
        google()
        mavenCentral()
        jcenter()
    }
    dependencies {
        classpath("com.android.tools.build:gradle:3.2.1")
        classpath(kotlin("gradle-plugin", version = "1.3.11"))
    }
}

allprojects {
    repositories {
        google()
        mavenCentral()
        jcenter()
    }
}
```

App build.gradle.kts

```
import org.jetbrains.kotlin.config.KotlinCompilerVersion

plugins {
    id("com.android.application")
    kotlin("android")
    kotlin("android.extensions")
}

android {
    compileSdkVersion(28)
    defaultConfig {
        applicationId = "com.a.b.c"
        minSdkVersion(15)
        targetSdkVersion(28)
        versionCode = 1
        versionName = "1.0"
        testInstrumentationRunner = "android.support.test.runner.AndroidJUnitRunner"
    }
    buildTypes {
        getByName("release") {
            isMinifyEnabled = false
            proguardFiles(getDefaultProguardFile("proguard-android.txt"), "proguard-rules.pro")
        }
    }

    // experimental mode is enabled -> @Parcelize should be resolved
    androidExtensions {
        isExperimental = true
    }
}

dependencies {
    implementation(kotlin("stdlib-jdk7", KotlinCompilerVersion.VERSION))
    ... other dependencies ...
```

I tried moving

```
    androidExtensions {
        isExperimental = true
    }
```

from android to top level but still outcome was the same. Anyone had similar issue and managed to solve this?

Comment: Same error for me 

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Ah! I located [a working solution](https://github.com/gradle/kotlin-dsl/issues/644#issuecomment-356605347). Set the experimental flag in a Groovy-based `androidExtensions.gradle` then `apply` that file in your Kotlin-based `build.gradle.kts`.

I wanted to pass it along but credit goes to [toxxmeister](https://github.com/toxxmeister).

Comment: Thank you for posting this workaround. This also works: https://github.com/gradle/kotlin-dsl/issues/644#issuecomment-454594727 There is also bug filed at https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/KT-22213 to fix this issue.

Answer (score 30):

All you need to do is add below plugin to your app level gradle file

```
apply plugin: 'kotlin-parcelize'
```

PS:  `apply plugin: 'kotlin-android-extensions'` is deprecated.

Comment: I don't think this works anymore. `kotlin-parcelize` is not found by gradle.

Comment: Thank you for this suggestion!
PS: Note that you should change the import if your previously used the kotlin-extension to "import kotlinx.parcelize.Parcelize"

Answer (score 23):

In my case.
Just swap 2 line of code kotlin-android and kotlin-android-extensions then it work.

So the sequence below is work:

```
apply plugin: 'com.android.application'
apply plugin: 'kotlin-android'
apply plugin: 'kotlin-android-extensions'
```

Comment: apply plugin: 'kotlin-android-extensions' is deprecated.

Answer (score 1):

Add this Plugin in your build.gradle(app) file.

id 'kotlin-android-extensions'

Answer (score 0):

https://github.com/gradle/kotlin-dsl-samples/issues/644#issuecomment-482479624 - 
As commented on this link,

```
androidExtensions { isExperimental = true }
```

works fine for me when I upgraded the Kotlin version to the latest one i.e. 1.3.60 and no need to do any workaround.

Comment: Throws error : `Could not set unknown property 'isExperimental' for object of type org.jetbrains.kotlin.gradle.internal.AndroidExtensionsExtension.`

Comment: @RamakrishnaJoshi are you using kotlin DSL for gradle? and have you upgraded kotlin version to the latest as mentioned above?

Comment: My bad, I am using a separate module for network calls which is independent of Android. So can't use androidExtensions { isExperimental = true }
there. Your answer is not an issue.

Answer (score 0):

For Kotlin KTS

this solution worked for me

```
androidExtensions {
    configure(delegateClosureOf<AndroidExtensionsExtension> {
        isExperimental = true
    })
}
```

My `build.gradle.kts` file

```
plugins {
    id(Dependencies.androidApplication)
    id(Dependencies.google)
    id(Dependencies.kotlinAndroid)
    id(Dependencies.kotlinAndroidExtensions)
    id(Dependencies.kapt)
    id(Dependencies.crashlytics)
}

androidExtensions{
    configure(delegateClosureOf<org.jetbrains.kotlin.gradle.internal.AndroidExtensionsExtension> {
        isExperimental = true
    })
}

android {
......
}
```

for more details 
https://github.com/gradle/kotlin-dsl-samples/issues/644#issuecomment-398502551

Answer (score 0):

Make sure you have ***`this`*** import in your list of imports

```
import kotlinx.parcelize.Parcelize
```

In my case even though I had plugins applied as mentioned in the answers, Android studio was importing the wrong plugin.